# If you break ancestry, would you have to start security process from scratch?

Tags: appexchange, security-review

If you break ancestry, would you have to start security process from scratch?

I know that if you want to create a package from a different dev hub, you would have to restart the security review process from scratch, and the package version won't be autoapproved, but you will have to wait for a real security review. However, what if you just break the ancestry and create a package version which doesn't have the common ancestor with package version which is published on AppExchange, would you have to restart the security review process again or will it be auto-approved like for the 1GMP and 2GMP which share the common ancestor version id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I have just checked it.

The version, which doesn't share the common ancestor version with published version on AppExchange, was autoapproved by Security Review process.

Still I think it is better to use only package version which share the common ancestor. However, unfortunately, Permission Set Groups cannot be removed from a package, so the only option is to create a package version which doesn't share the common ancestor.

Comment: I think the point here is that the package ID is what drives the review status, not version IDs.